# Is Zeroconf API available in Android?

Tags: android

Does android 2.2 have support for Zeroconf and MDNS related APIs ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jmdns http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmdns/ 
I have used it to discover Bonjour/Zeroconf related services with good accuracy with Android 2.2. Depending on your need, you may need to tweak their code a bit in order to get better discovery.

Note that some of older HTC phones have bugs with the multicast, but I think they have fixed it in their recent phones